# Solana devnet is not processing transactions

Tags: devnet

I've tried to make a few SOL transfer transactions via the Phantom Wallet. I received the transaction hash, but the actual transfer didn't happen, and there is no data by this hash on the explorer (solscan devnet).
The faucet also didn't send any devnet SOL at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devnet is currently down, it was restarted 3 hourse ago with the paramters:

```
solana-ledger-tool --ledger ~/ledger --snapshot-archive-path ~/ledger-snapshots create-snapshot 276140931 --hard-fork 276140931
```

bank hash: CfDraamXRmQ92zmhFFZMcp4cDcj4D48UNiBmUCBTekWV
shred version: 38239

Some nodes probably still need to catch up for it to be properly usable again.

You can follow the developement here:
https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/749059399875690557

and the investigation here:
https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/1201868800652496926